# Load text from url convert to json and create list from Binance API

Tags: python, json, list

I am trying to create a list from a url that I have converted to json. I am trying to filter the json list and load the objects into a list then iterate through the list.

```
    requestT = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices')
    json_dataT = json.loads(requestT.text)
    ticker_list = json_dataT['symbol']
    return;
```

`

I get an error stating, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I cant seem to find an example of text to json to list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the complete list to get the values, here is the corrected version of code in which ticker_list will give you list of all the symbols present in the result from the api.

```
import requests
import json

requestT = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices')
json_dataT = json.loads(requestT.text)

ticker_list=[]
for data in json_dataT:
    ticker_list.append( data['symbol'])

print ticker_list
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_dataT` is a `list` of `dicts`. To access the `value` of `'symbol'` in each `dict`, you could try this:

```
import requests
import json

requestT = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices')
json_dataT = json.loads(requestT.text)
ticker_list = [d['symbol'] for d in json_dataT]

>>> ticker_list
['ETHBTC', 'LTCBTC', 'BNBBTC', 'NEOBTC', '123456', 'QTUMETH', 'EOSETH', 'SNTETH', ...]
```